# Сортировка массива. Js

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с вопросом.
Работаю с World of Tanks API, получаю Id всех танков игрока.
Тут же запрашиваю информацию по айди (Название танка, количество боев игрока на данном танке).

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    tankName[i] = json.data[accId][i].name
    tankBattles[i] = json.data[accId][i].all.battles
}
```

В итоге получаются два массива, в которых tankName[1] соответствует tankBattles[1] и т.д.
Нужно показать пользователю список (Название, количество боев), но так, что бы танки сортировались от Большего количества боев, до Меньшего.

Извините за не очень ясную постановку вопроса, пишу впервые...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делайте сразу правильно и пусть зависимые элементы будут в одном объекте:

```js
let tanks   = [{tankName: 'Я танк 1', battles: ['Битвы танка 1'], score: 45}, {tankName: 'Танк 2', battles: ['Второго танка битвы'], score: 154}, {tankName: 'Третий танк', battles: ['Танка 3 битвы'], score: 12}];

let sortedTanks = tanks.sort((f, s) => f.score < s.score);
console.info(sortedTanks);
```

Comment: Battles - числовое значение. Мне кажется, так лучше:

`let tanks   = [{tankName: 'Я танк 1', battles: 45}, {tankName: 'Танк 2', battles: 154}, {tankName: 'Третий танк', battles: 12}];

let sortedTanks = tanks.sort((f, s) => f.battles< s.battles);
console.info(sortedTanks);`

Comment: @ИльяАтамас, делайте как Вам удобнее, я лишь концепцию озвучил.